# Including html parts in another html files

Tags: php, html, css

I'm working on a "plain" HTML-CSS website. It contains several pages. I want some code to be included in all HTML pages. (All have a navbar at the top)

What is the best way to include that part of the code in all files in order to avoid repeating code?

I've tried creating a directory named "partials", there I added a file called header.html and then tried including it in a different file with PHP. like so:

```
<?php include "./partials/header.html" ?>
```

This is not working. Please advise me what to do.

Thanks!

Comment: _..I'm working on a "plain" HTML-CSS website.._ Why are you expecting php to work in a html file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Comment: @B001ᛦ The home page though is rendered using index.php which contains:

<?php header( 'Location: /home' ) ;  ?>

So you could call it a "php" project

Comment: _..The home page though is rendered using index.php..._ well then it is not plain html css. Check the path to the html file or look at @VishnuBhadoriya duplicate suggestion

Comment: _...which contains: <?php header( 'Location: /home' ) ;_ Doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya I've seen this, it doesn't answer my question unfortunately. I didn't understand it. Someone said it only works on a server and not on a local machine.

Comment: @B001ᛦ This is not my issue. It's working.

Comment: @B001ᛦ maybe he is using **<?php ?>** inside a .html file :D

Comment: a normal `<?php include(path/to/file) ?>` would work

Comment: @KebabProgrammer Hey, I've tried doing it with PHP inside html. Exactly. But it didn't work :(

Comment: are all your files ending with a `.php`? If they aren't then its probably why your include isn't working

Comment: @KebabProgrammer They're not ending with a .php because they are HTML files. Do I have to change all html file endings to .php?

Comment: The browser needs to know that it's intepreting a php file, so that any php markup inside the file will be intepreted correctly. if you have your `<?php ?>` inside a `.html` file, it will get ignored. and about 3 comments up, i posted how to properly include a file

Comment: @OriSilberman you can copy over the contents, eg `header.html` into `header.php`, this way the include will be picked up. you would then have something like `<?php include("partial/header.php")`. that should fix your issue

Comment: It did look like the php statement was commented out. But, after renaming the file which contains the php statement to a .php, another problem occured. Whenever I click the anchor tag to go to that page (menu.php) it doesn't go to that page but tries installing it.

Comment: You can include documents inside other documents without using PHP using server side includes. Rename .html files to .shtml files, then you can include files like this:
`<!--#include virtual="../quote.txt" -->`. Note that this only works in Apache, not nginx.

Answer (score 1):

From what you answer and ask on the reply’s under your question I wonder if you are aware Php code only works when run on a server? You can create your own server environment locally using Xampp.